# What benefits are there to having a homeworld with a higher threat level?

Tags: starbound

I made the first snow planet I found in the alpha sector my homeworld and have been slowly working on my castle. I am wondering if maybe I should wait before getting too comfortable on this planet if there are more benefits to being on a tougher planet?

Comment: I've actually wondered if there's any reason for a homeworld at all, beyond "I want to build something cool-looking here".

Comment: @Sterno That's basically it. And why does there *need* to be a reason? Building cool-looking stuff is its own reward, IMHO.

Comment: @Sterno I quickly ran out of enough space to store stuff where I could organize it on my ship. Next character wipe, I'm going to use my home world for more storage.

Comment: @kevin thats why I like having a homeworld, hopefully the selling feature comes soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Planets in different/later sectors can have different allocations of ore, as well as different Biomes not available in the Alpha sector.

Note that the ore distribution differences *can* be a double edged sword - if you are doing something that needs Iron (say, you downloaded a new mod that requires Iron for its crafting station) but your home planet is in Delta or X Sector, you're quite unlikely to find it in any reasonable quantities. You'll also be unable to build your planet on a Tentacle or Magma planet in Alpha sector, because they aren't *present* there.

The flipside to this, however, is that on lower-level planets (like in Alpha sector), you're at considerably less risk of murder, mutilation, and mayhem caused by the local wildlife. Even Impervium armor only goes so far on threat level 10 planets in Sector X, but it will basically invalidate the threat of enemies in Alpha Sector.

Answer (score 0):

The benefits of a higher level homeword are:

- Have higher level ores that are not available in lower level planets.
- Have more ores of lower levels. For example on lower level planets diamond ore may be very seldom while in higher level iot may be very common (precious metals and diamonds are a good source of pixels)
- Better rewards in chests
- Wildlife may drop more pixels if killed (not sure in this)

Answer (score 0):

The way that I have been playing the game my home world was originally for exploration, but now it sole purpose is housing my base of operations. I explore the stars (and collect ore), and then teleport back to my home world to craft and farm. Therefore, the ore at the planet doesn't really have any influence on my home world.